# Rails survey style application - Show all answers on option

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, voting, vote

I'm a new guy to ruby on rails and working on my first in-depth application. It has four tables: **Questions**, **Options**, **Answers** and **Users**. There's a list of questions and a user can vote for a unique option (stored in the Answers join table), I'm trying to get my head around table associations.

[image: This is an example of how I'm using the database, minus the Survey and Survey Question]

This is how I've setup my individual RB files:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :options
     has_many :answers, :through => :options
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :option
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    has_many :questions, :through => :answers 
end
```

My questions controller is setup like this to include the options table:

```
@questions = Question.includes(:options).all
```

and the table body in my index.html.erb file:

```
<tbody>
   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('lineOdd', 'lineEven') %>">
         <td><%= question.question_text %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Show', question %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <% question.options.each do |option_text| %>
         <tr class="backgroundColor1">
            <td class="optionCell"> <%= option_text.option_text %> </td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

In the Question class I've used 'has_many :answers, :through => :options' - is this the correct way to go about this and how would I output the total number of votes in a table row below the associated option.

Do I need to add to or change the question controller code?

This is my first post, sorry if I'm not informative enough!

Thanks

Comment: Really refreshing to see a first question that is well though out and includes all the relevant info. Good job.

Comment: Ah thanks - I'm really enjoying Rails at the moment so I'll hopefully stick around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by fixing up the relations a bit:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers
end
```

There is nothing technically wrong with `has_many :answers, :through => :options` but since there is a direct relation through `answers.question_id` we don't need to go through the `options` table for the relation.

## Displaying the count

If we simply did:

```
<td class="optionCell"><%= option.answers.count %></td>
```

This would create a nasty `n+1` query to fetch the count of the answers for each option. So what we want to do is [create a counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) which stores a tally on the options table.

Lets start by creating a migration to add the column:

```
rails g migration AddAnswerCounterCacheToOptions answers_count:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then we tell ActiveRecord to update the tally when we create associated records, this looks a bit strange since the `counter_cache: true` declaration is on the `belongs_to` side while the column is on the other but thats just how AR works.

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :option, counter_cache: true
end
```

There is a little snag here. Since we may already have records we need to make sure they have correct counters. You can do this from the console but in the long run it is a good idea to [create a rake task](http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/).

```
Option.find_each { |option| Option.reset_counters(option.id, :answers) }
```

This might take a bit of time since it needs to pull each Option and update the count.

Now we can display the tally like so:

```
<% question.options.each do |option| %>
  <tr class="backgroundColor1">
    <td class="optionCell"><%= option.option_text %></td>
    <td class="optionCell"><%= option.answers.size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

`.size` is smart enough to use our counter cache column, but will fall back to querying the count which is a good thing for tests.

Comment: The alternative to `counter_cache` is to write a select clause which fetches the count in a subquery. Not really recommended for a beginner since you really need to know how ActiveRecord builds queries and loads relations.

Comment: Thank you so much, really useful! :-)